# Seams on normal map

Tags: uv, blender-internal-render-engine, normals, texture-baking

so I have a arm model, and I baked a normal map for from a sculpt. However, when I apply this normal map in any program (Blender, Unreal, Unity) there are seams on it. (from the UVs). This is ugly and I'm not sure why its happening. Please help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDunm.png)

Comment: I don't think the seams are particularly bad here, if you had any kind of texture applied you couldn't probably notice it. In the image the polygons being distinguishable in the silhouette is far more disturbing to the eye. But you could still look into it. Why is there are UV mapping seam there, is this animated model? Normals are seamless when geometry has the same normal and the normal map colors match, so one of those things is slightly off. Can you supply the model and the map for investigating the issue?

Comment: If it persist in other software, then your normal map is baked incorrectly. You'll need to show how you baked the map, what settings, how you prepared the meshes etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using cycles you probably forgot to switch your image texture node from color to non-color data. This will hide the seam significantly. Also creating a higher resolution normals map will help as well.

[image] [image: Image description here]

Comment: If this problem persists on other platforms outside Blender it's not related to Cycles nodes?

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution. Just put the mode of your Normal map node (image texture) from Srgb to Non-Color

Answer (score 0):

If seen this several times. In my experience it is due to weird uv mapping. Try to unwrap your model different. I find these edges occur when some connected faces are not connected in the uv map